# List multiple 'options' (CakePHP 3)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

*I'm new to CakePHP 3 so let me know if I need to add more details.*

I am editing the add.ctp page and trying to list all available options.
I am trying to list the five personality traits (Prideful, Respectful, Pervasent, Loyal, Bold and Disciplined) that are in my database.

How would I go about listing all these options with the ability to add the value for each?

Here is the current code:

```
echo $this->Form->control('name_id', ['options' => $names]);
echo $this->Form->control('personalities_id', ['options' => $personalities]);
echo $this->Form->control('value');
```

example of what I need:

```
name
Prideful, Value 
Respectful, Value 
Pervasent, Value 
Loyal, Value 
Bold, Value 
Disciplined, Value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create the inputs through looping.  I'm not sure what the `$personalities` array or your controller action looks like, but this is the basic idea.

```
foreach ($personalities as $personality) {
    echo $this->Form->text("{$personality}");
}
```

[Cakephp 3 Form Docs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-input-elements)